# (Angular) How do I override the (mouseenter) and (mouseleave) functions for ngbootstrap carousels?

Tags: node.js, angular, carousel, ng-bootstrap, mouseleave

I'm currently trying to create a carousel that plays Youtube videos in Angular with ngbootstrap. I've managed to successfully embed the videos but I've noticed that the (mouseenter) and (mouseleave) functions that the bootstrap carousel comes with is calling pause() and cycle(), both of which make the video start to reload/replay each time your mouse enters or exits the carousel space. I want to override them to prevent this from happening.

I've looked through node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/carousel for a way to possibly override them but I don't see anything that'll do so.

I found a ngbootstrap github source that appears to have a file that allows for overrides:

https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/carousel/carousel.ts

but being new to Angular I'm not sure if I don't have the same ngbootstrap, or if I couldn't find these files or what. Let me know if more information is needed!

Comment: Can you add a small online demo of what you try to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I recently found an answer from someone on reddit! I needed to add `pointer-events : none` to ngb-carousel.